# Deploy and expose chaincode as REST api on amazon managed blockchain hyperledger fabric 1.2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, amazon-managed-blockchain

I have configured amazon managed blockchain setup with Hyperledger 1.2. The network is prepared with a single member and a single peer node.
Hyperledger Fabric Client setup is with Golang 1.10.3. I have installed, Instantiated, Queried and Invoked mycc chaincode example given in AWS tutorial. Which works perfectly. Complete exercise was done following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html) link.

I want to deploy and expose the chaincode as REST api.
There is a sample project [Amazon Managed Blockchain Workshop](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain).
They have used RESTful API, running as a Node.js Express application, using the Hyperledger Fabric Client SDK to query and invoke chaincode.
I want to run non-profit chaincode example on Hyperledger Fabric Client prepared for AWS managed Blockchain Hyper Ledger 1.2

I have performed below steps:

- Part 2: Deploy the [non-profit chaincode](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-chaincode/README.md))
- Part 3: RESTful API to expose the Chaincode

Here are the steps how am I am running and testing the REST API.

```
cd ~/non-profit-blockchain/ngo-rest-api
nvm use lts/carbon
node app.js &
```

If I execute Register/enroll a user request

```
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:3000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=john&orgName=Org1'
```

Instead of showing: response:

> {"success":true,"secret":"","message":"michael enrolled Successfully"}

It shows below error message.

> {"success":false,"message":"failed Error: Missing mspid parameter"}

I have also tried by adding mspid in the request but the error message is still same. What am I missing?

Here are contents of ngo-connection-profile.yaml

```
channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.com
    peers:
      peer1:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
<pre><code>
organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid:
    peers:
      - peer1
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-org1
orderers:
  orderer.com:
    url: grpcs://orderer.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30001
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem
</pre></code>
peers:
  peer1:
    url: grpcs://nd-NDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDND.m-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS....
    eventUrl: grpcs://nd-NDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDND.m-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS.....
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: nd-NDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDNDND.m-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS.xxx
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  ca-org1:
    url: https://ca.m-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.n-XDXDXDXDXDSXDSXDXSDXSDXDSXDSXDS....
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: aaaaaaaa
        enrollSecret: XXXXXXXXXXX
    caName: m-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Guys can any one help me that. Can we create rest server in windows OS?. I have successfully created ad installed chain code in aws. Just I want to query it in windows local using node sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I am also exploring Amazon Managed Blockchain although its in preview. Hopefully I will be able to assist you in your issue. mspid is not a parameter to be sent in the request. It looks that you are missing some-thing in the configuration file. Can you send me the contents of below configuration file?

```
cat ~/non-profit-blockchain/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
```

While looking at the contents of the configuration file, it is obvious that mspid value is missing in the configuration file. Membership Service Providers (MSP) ID is a mandatory value to be set in the configuration. You can also confirm it with below command.

```
cat ~/non-profit-blockchain/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml | grep mspid:
```

If it is showing empty value then you need to set mspid in the configuration file.
Make sure that the environment variables mentioned in

```
~/non-profit-blockchain/ngo-fabric/fabric-exports.sh
```

are properly set. If this file is missing then use

```
~/non-profit-blockchain/ngo-fabric/templates/exports-template.sh
```

You need to set the value of environment variable ${MEMBERID} in mspid in ngo-connection-profile.yaml, also see if any other required field value is missing in the configuration file. You can also see the detail of values required t be replacs in the configuration file from below script.

```
~/non-profit-blockchain/ngo-rest-api/connection-profile/gen-connection-profile.sh
```

.
Let me list down those as well.

```
sed -i "s|%PEERNODEID%|$PEERNODEID|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%MEMBERID%|$MEMBERID|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%CAFILE%|$LOCALCA|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%ORDERINGSERVICEENDPOINT%|$ORDERINGSERVICEENDPOINT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%ORDERINGSERVICEENDPOINTNOPORT%|$ORDERINGSERVICEENDPOINTNOPORT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%PEERSERVICEENDPOINT%|$PEERSERVICEENDPOINT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%PEERSERVICEENDPOINTNOPORT%|$PEERSERVICEENDPOINTNOPORT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%PEEREVENTENDPOINT%|$PEEREVENTENDPOINT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%CASERVICEENDPOINT%|$CASERVICEENDPOINT|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%ADMINUSER%|$ADMINUSER|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
sed -i "s|%ADMINPWD%|$ADMINPWD|g" $REPODIR/tmp/connection-profile/ngo-connection-profile.yaml
```

After setting the values and verifying, stop node or kill the process running on port 3000 and run node again.
cd ~/non-profit-blockchain/ngo-rest-api

```
nvm use lts/carbon
node app.js &
```

Comment: I have added the contents of ngo-connection-profile.yaml in the main question.

Comment: Yes you were right, mspid was missing and after setting this value restarting node, now I am able to send both api requests. (Register/enroll a user), (POST a Donor) and (Get all donors). Thanks Bajwa

Comment: Hi @Moolshanker Kothari, Do you tried to run the same ngo-rest-api project locally in windows?

Comment: Nop, I have deployed on Ubuntu 18.04